# Hibernate: entities mapping

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have an entity, let's call it **"Question"**. This entity has set of **"Answer"** entities. So, for example:

Question: "How old are you?"

Answer: "16", "15", "21", "26"

The correct answer is "21".

This mapping looks like:

Question:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
private Set<Answer> answers;
```

Answer:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
private Question question;
```

It's very clear. But then, I would like to have question where are several parts and even more answers, e.g.:

Question: x = 1, please attach correct variants:

Parts:

1. x + 1
2. x + 2
3. 2 * (x + 1)

Answers:

1. 2
2. 12
3. 51
4. 3
5. 4
6. 123

So, how could I map such cases? I would like to implement it as clear as possible and not to corrupt my db structure. Thank you.

Comment: will the current question part be dependent on the answer given in the previous part?

Comment: @jmw5598 The Question is dependent on all parts (for example for all parts answers were correct, so the question was correct)

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that "parts" exists? Couldn't you assume "parts" as anothers Questions?

Comment: yeap, I thought about that, but is that OK?